# Azure Devops API - Get top level portfolio work item types

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to get a list of work item types per level in Azure Devops using the API and the following:

`dev.azure.com/{collection_name}/{project_id}/_apis/work/processconfiguration`

which does indeed bring me almost all the information about the process type work item levels. However it doesn't bring me any of the top level work items that I've added to the portfolio level as shown below.

[image]

I would think it should be included in the Portfolio backlog here but only epics and features are included.

[image]

Is there an API available where I can get the top level work item types for a given process or project?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I tested create a new Portfolio backlog and found the API is using: `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/work/processes/{processid}/behaviors`

And search the REST API found the following:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workitemtypesbehaviors/{witRefNameForBehaviors}/behaviors?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

In your case, you could use the following API to list the Portfolio backlogs:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/behaviors?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work-item-types-behaviors/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP).